# Google Chrome is not connecting to Internet - Error code: ERR_FAILED

Tags: google-chrome

Chrome will not connect to the Internet at all. It happens instantaneously when requesting a URL - seems like it is not getting past my computer. I get:

Error code: ERR_FAILED.

I have disabled the firewall, AVG and still ... no luck. I have uninstalled with Revo uninstall and cleaned and registry entries and leftover files. No luck. I have changed Proxy settings to "Automatically Detect Settings". No luck.

Anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

please try to modify some  antivirus  setting  or disable it  and try again.